# SQL:insert into $_POST and output JSON

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, post

(1)I’d like to make this file receive `$_POST[‘message’]`, and insert into db.
(2)I’d like to make this file output db data on JSON.

But nothing is output even though some data stored in db.
I have this code.

MySQL

```
CREATE DATABASE chat;
CREATE TABLE posts(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, message TEXT);
```

index.php

```
mb_language("uni");
mb_internal_encoding("utf-8");
mb_http_input("auto");
mb_http_output("utf-8");

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
if ($link) {
    die('cannot connect:'.mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("chat", $link);

if ($SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (message) VALUES ('$message')");
}

$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC');
$posts = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
    $posts[] = array(
        'message' = $row -> message
        );
}

header('Content-Type:application/json');
echo json_encode($posts);

?>
```

How do I fix it to output JSON?

Comment: You have a lot more to fix than just the JSON output. For a start: stop using the _deprecated_ `mysql_*` extension, and fix that gaping injection vulnerability

Comment: What exactly is getting stored in the db?

Comment: @AustinMullins is $row->message same as $row['message'] ??

Comment: @user3493922 what does $row->message  do ?? what it fetches ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace:

'message' = $row -> message

'message' => $row -> message

But also , you should use

SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = mysql_insert_id()

Comment: ...i have a doubt ..actually what does 'meesage => $row->message do ..i know $row->message fetch the message variable ie $_POST['message'] but why are we using inside an array ?